# $f(x, y, z)$ is continuous near $(0, 0, 0)$. Find $\lim_{p\rightarrow +0} \iiint\limits_{D_r}f(x, y, z) dxdydz$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, analysis

I have $$D_{r} = \left\{ {(x, y, z) | x, y, z \geq 0, x+y+z \leq r}\right\}$$
And I have to find
$$\lim_{r\rightarrow +0} \frac{1}{r^3} \iiint\limits_{D_r}^{} f(x, y, z)  dxdydz$$

I have problems with that paremeter $r$, how it affects in limit? How can I solve that limit?

Comment: $p$ never shows up again inside the integral. As it stands the limit doesn't exist ($\pm \infty$ depending on the sign of the integral).

Comment: Could it be a typo and the p is supposed to be r?

Comment: yep it was a mistake, p = r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to rescale the variables.

By the change of variable $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=(\frac{x}{r},\frac{y}{r},\frac{z}{r})$, you get $d\alpha  \ d\beta \ d\gamma = \frac{1}{r^3}dx \ dy \ dz$ so

$$
\int_{D_r} f(x,y,z) \ dx \ dy \ dz =
\int_{D_1} f(\alpha r,\beta r,\gamma r) \ d\alpha \ d\beta \ d\gamma
$$

Now for $r$ sufficiently small, $r \mapsto f(\alpha r,\beta r,\gamma r)$ is bounded and thus integrable on $D_1$ because $f$ is continuous at $0$. Moreover $f(\alpha r,\beta r,\gamma r)$ tends to $f(0,0,0)$ as $r$ tends to zero, by continuity of $f$. So the dominated convergence gives you that the limit is
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{D_1} f(0,0,0) \ d\alpha \ d\beta \ d\gamma
&= f(0,0,0) \int_0^1 \left( \int_0^{1-\alpha} \left( \int_0^{1-\alpha-\beta} d\gamma \right) d\beta \right) d\alpha \\
&= f(0,0,0) \int_0^1 \left( \int_0^{1-\alpha} \left( 1-\alpha-\beta\right) d\beta \right) d\alpha \\\
&= f(0,0,0) \int_0^1  \frac{(1-\alpha)^2}{2} d\alpha \\
&= \frac{1}{6}f(0,0,0)
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Observe
\begin{align}
\left|\iiint_{D_r} f(x, y, z) dV - f(0, 0, 0) \text{vol}(D_r) \right|= &\ \left|\iiint_{D_r}f(x, y, z)-f(0,0, 0)\ dV \right|\\
\le&\ \iiint_{D_r}|f(x, y, z)-f(0, 0, 0)| dV\\
\le&\ \varepsilon \text{vol}(D_r) = \varepsilon \frac{1}{6} r^3. 
\end{align}
for $r$ sufficiently small.

Comment: what means "vol"?

Comment: The volume of $D_r$ would be $\frac{1}{2}r^3$

Comment: ah, I get it, thanks

Comment: The volume of $D_r$ is $\frac{r^3}{6}$. You can see that either by computing the triple integral or by noticing that it is a pyramid of height $r$ and of base a right isosceles triangle of area $r^2/2$ so the volume is $\frac{1}{3} \times \text{base_area} \times \text{height} = \frac{1}{3} \times r^2/2 \times r = \frac{r^3}{6}$. The intuition that the plane $x+y+z = r$ splits the cube of side $r$ in two equal parts is false

Comment: Ops. I misread. I thought it was a ball.